# NestJs reusing a guard that has uses multiple service gives "a Invalid guard passed to @UseGuards()" error

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-passport

I'm trying to retrieve the current user in a guard to give him access or no.
I have a guard that isn't doing anything for now

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor (
    private readonly studentService: StudentService,
    private readonly agencyService: AgencyService
  ) {
    super()
  }
}
```

When I add it to two controllers like that

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard /* CrudAbilitiesGuard */)
  @ApiBearerAuth('access-token')
  @ApiBody({ type: CreateStudentDto })
  @Post()
  async create (
    @Body() newStudentDto: CreateStudentDto
  ): Promise<StudentDocument> {
    const student = await this.service.create(newStudentDto)
    if (student == null) throw new InternalServerErrorException()
    return student
  }
```

it throws `Error: Invalid guard passed to @UseGuards() decorator`

if I only use the guard in one controller, it works fine, if I comment both the services in the constructor and use it in two controllers, it also works.
Seems like nest a casual hidden circular dependency but i really can't get my head around it

Edit:

Same result with a Guard that extends CanActivate directly

```
@Injectable()
export class CrudAbilitiesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor (
    private readonly agencyService: AgencyService,
    private readonly studentService: StudentService,
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
    private readonly caslAbilityFactory: CaslAbilityFactory
  ) {}
  async canActivate (context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: So, I moved the user retrieval in the Strategy so I didn't have to inject the services, but I'm still interested if there's a workaround when you need to use multiple services in a guard

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, massive noob mistake. In an effort of not having 300+ files I had small modules in the same file (service + controller + schemas, etc) leading to of course billions of inter-dependency and circular issues of all kinds.
Note to myself: **Module means MODULE**

Comment: Can you provide what the exact mistake was?

Comment: @SarenTasciyan I had controller, service, schema and module for an entity in the same file, instead of simply having one for each.

Answer (score 0):

Tye to put guard decorator closer before the method (after API descriptors)

BTW, In NestJS there is already *JwtAuthGuard* (https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#overriding-globally-registered-enhancers)

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_GUARD,
    useExisting: JwtAuthGuard,
    // ^^^^^^^^ notice the use of 'useExisting' instead of 'useClass'
  },
  JwtAuthGuard,
],
```

Comment: Issue is solved already. Decorators order has no importance in nestJS, only UseGuards(1, 2) does that

Comment: No, there's no default JwtAuthGuard. It's just the sample code in the official guide. Like [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-jwt).

Answer (score -1):

[From docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards):

> A Guard is a class annotated with the @Injectable() decorator, which implements the **CanActivate** interface.

Try to provide some implementation for `CanActivate` inside the guard itself

Comment: my guard extends `AuthGuard`, implementing a `CanActivate` already